# Combining videos of different framerates?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Been playing around with the video editor on Blender for a few days. Right now I'm trying to combine a few videos with different framerates (23.99FPS and 25FPS). Is it possible to get them to work together without one being desynced?

Comment: I did this a long time back but the VSE wasn't very good at it.  I had to do it in the 3D window.  A 2D plane was textured with the video and that 'filmed' with the camera.  To my surprise it did quite a good job.  One had sound and there was no loss of sync.  The output was rendered using OpenGL and input framerate was 30, output 25.  As for mixing videos of differing framerates, 2 or more planes would be needed and rendered out using Blender's internal render because the planes'  texture opacity can't be keyframed with OpenGL.

Comment: Correction to the above - videos not using an alpha layer such as text on transparency can still be lap-dissolved/cross-faded using the material slot's transparency slider.  Both video textured planes would need their specular sliders wound down to zero and tick the "Shadeless" box in the 'shading' tab.  It text on transparency is required, then the text's fading would require Blender's internal render.  That needs the Texture properties' 'Alpha' slider down in the 'Influence' panel.